# $A$ closed iff every limit of convergent sequences in $A$ is in $A$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have proven the following propositions,

> **Proposition 1**: Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\mathbf{x}\in \overline{A}$ iff there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to $\mathbf{x}$.

> **Proposition 2**: Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $A$ is closed iff every sequence in $A$ converges to a point in $A$.

where the latter was done by proof by contradiction and used the fact that $A$ is open iff $A^c$ is closed. Now, by random, when I saw in [Proposition 9.6](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/9-2.pdf), page three, it indicates that it is possible to prove Proposition 2 using Proposition 1 above. How?

Here is what I thought about the proof:

"Only if:" Assume $A$ is closed, and assume that $(x_n)$ is any sequence in $A$ that converges to some point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. By proposition 1, we have $x\in \overline{A}$. Since $A$ is assumed to be closed, we have $x\in A$. Is this approach correct? I feel it doesn't, because proposition 1 does not talk about every sequence.

"If": Assume $(x_n)$ is any sequence in $A$ that converges to some point $x\in A$. Then, by proposition 1, we have $x\in \overline{A}$. Here, I am supposed to show that $\overline{A}\subseteq A$. Or, was it because that $(x_n)$ already converges, so its limit must belong to $\overline{A}$, and since its limit was in $A$ by assumption, would it mean that $\overline{A}\subseteq A$? Perhaps, I should reformulate proposition a bit more clear, like:

> **Proposition 2'**: Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $A$ is closed iff every sequence in $A$ that converges to some point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ implies $x\in A$.

I do not know if it makes any difference.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of [solution-verification](/questions/tagged/solution-verification), let's pick this apart:

> "Only if": ... Is this approach correct? I feel it doesn't, because proposition 1 does not talk about every sequence.

It is correct. Proposition 1 just demands that a sequence (any sequence) exists, with points in $A$, that converge to $x$. If we meet these demands, then Proposition 1 tells us that $x \in \overline{A}$. You have such a sequence by assumption, so the conclusion is valid.

> "If": ...

This is all a bit muddled and trails off without a conclusion, I think because you started your proof in the middle, rather than at the beginning. Focus on what you are trying to prove: you want to show $A$ is closed, or as you yourself said, $\overline{A} \subseteq A$.

So, start by assuming that $x \in \overline{A}$. What does Proposition 1 give you? Then, use your assumption from Proposition 2. Let me know in a comment if you need further help.

Comment: Would it then be correct to say: Let $$B:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid \text{there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to some point in } A\}.$$Then, by proposition 1, we have $B=\overline{A}$. Now, assume $A$ closed, and let $(x_n)$ be any sequence converging to a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, since $x\in B$, we have $x\in \overline{A}=A$, proving one direction. Assume conversely that every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ converges to some point $x\in A$. Assume $y\in \overline{A}$. Then $y\in B$. By assumption, we have $y\in A$, so $B\subseteq A$. Hence $A$ closed, proving the other direction.

Comment: Change it to$$B:= \{ x \in \Bbb{R} \mid \text{there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$}\},$$and yes, it's good.